# Indent requireJS files so that it's easy to add and delete included modules

Tags: javascript, dojo, requirejs, amd

I am trying to figure out the best way to indent my files. I am writing something using Dojo, and have some files with a lot of dependencies.

The hope:

- Each line is the same (especially the first one, and the last one)
- Easy to add/delete elements

At the moment, I am doing this:

```
define([
  "dojo/_base/declare",
  "dojo/topic",

  "dijit/Dialog",
  "dijit/_OnDijitClickMixin",
  "dijit/layout/BorderContainer",
  "dijit/layout/TabContainer",
  "dijit/layout/ContentPane",

  "hotplate/hotDojoStores/stores",
  "hotplate/hotDojoWidgets/_OverlayMixin",
  "hotplate/hotDojoGlobals/globals",
  "hotplate/hotDojoAuth/panels/Resume",
  "hotplate/hotDojoJade/DestroyableJadeTemplatedContainer",
  "hotplate/hotDojoStoreConfig/ConfigVars",
  "hotplate/hotDojoWidgets/util",
  "hotplate/hotDojoComet/_TabRegisterMixin",
  "hotplate/hotDojoAuth/_ReLoginMixin",

  "hotplate/bd/WorkspacesUsersConfig",
  "hotplate/bd/WorkspacesConfig",
  "hotplate/bd/UsersConfig",
  "hotplate/bd/Dashboard",
  "hotplate/bd/Contacts",

  ], function(

  declare
  , topic

  , Dialog
  , _OnDijitClickMixin
  , BorderContainer
  , TabContainer
  , ContentPane

  , stores
  , _OverlayMixin
  , globals
  , Resume
  , DestroyableJadeTemplatedContainer
  , ConfigVars
  , util
  , _TabRegisterMixin
  , _ReLoginMixin

  , WorkspacesUsersConfig
  , WorkspacesConfig
  , UsersConfig
  , Dashboard
  , Contacts

){
  var counter = 0;
});
```

Problems:

- There is an extra comma at the end of the last parameter. All modern browsers are OK with it, *but* IE9 still seems to choke on it. Yes of course I can delete it, but then it would break the first requirement, where each line is equal
- The first function parameter is different to the others (if course, missing comma)

What's the least painful way, or established standard, to indent requireJS files with a lot of modules?

Comment: This question is probably better suited for [codereview.se] than StackOverflow. That said, if you're investing time into the fact that there's an extra comma on one line, there's probably better things you could be doing.

Comment: Well I really care about my code, and want to make sure I have a good foundation. It's best to re-format 30 files than 300.

Comment: Besides, this is not about core reviewing, but a coding question -- although the question is about style...

Comment: As best as I can tell it's [on-topic for CR](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), though you could make an argument for [programmers.se] as well. I'm guessing that people at CR are more style-obsessed than people on SO and you're likely to get better responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the style that helps me avoid the most errors.

```
define([
    'dijit/form/DateTextBox'
    , 'dijit/form/FilteringSelect'
    , 'dijit/layout/ContentPane'        
    , 'dojo/_base/declare'
], function(
    DateTextBox
    , FilteringSelect
    , ContentPane
    , declare
){
    return declare(ContentPane, {
        postCreate: function() {
            // do stuff
        }
    });
});
```

- Leading commas.
- Alphabetically sorted args in the define function.

Comment: Absolutely the best idea. No trailing comma in arrays, and only the first item is "special".